# Dozer Mapping from string to Object

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I have:
`_class A` contains attributes: String userId, String a, String b.
How can I use Dozer Mapping to map `class A` to `class B` (and otherwise)
`_class B` has attributes: User user(object), String a,  String b. 
_'User' is also a class whose id is userId
Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do like this , with the assumption your class A and B look like this :**

```
 Class A{
 String userId;
 String a;
 String b;
 }

 Class B{
 User user;
 String a;
 String b;
 }

 Class User{
 String userId;
 }
```

> You have add below mapping in your mapping ".xml" file.

```
   <mapping> 
      <class-a>com.techidiocy.example.A</class-a>
      <class-b>com.techidiocy.example.B</class-b>   
        <field>
           <a>userId</a>
           <b>user.userId</b>
        </field>
   </mapping>
```